# How to save the objects in a Loop in HIbernate?

Tags: hibernate, loops

I am trying to save the objects i the Loop but its not working, Initially its insert the row in the table and then same row is updated for every loop.

PFB my code.

```
@Override
    public void saveConfirmDisposalAction(ConfirmDisposalAction confirmDisposal, List<Long> objectIDList) {
        for(ObjectCommon objectCommon : getObjectList(objectIDList)){
            confirmDisposal.setObjectId(objectCommon);
            confirmDisposal.setStorageLocation(objectCommon.getStorageLocation());
            objectActionService.saveObjectAction(confirmDisposal);
        }
    }
```

from getObjectList method, I am getting list of objects from database and iterate in the loop.
when I tried to save object of ConfirmDisposalAction model then only one row insert and the same row will update later on.

Kindly let me know, How I can fix this issue?

Appreciate for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not save every objects in the loop, try to use batch processing.

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                for (Object obj : list) {
                    String str = "";
                    statement.addBatch(str);
                    statement.executeBatch();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        SystemUtils.logException(ex);
        LOGGER.warn("Error ", ex);
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

This will do your job in single query.